# Javascript Regex - Undetermined number of vowels in a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a really long list of words `blacklist = ["sandwhich", "banana", "cheese"...]` and I am implementing a system to check if a text doesn't includes those words as substrings.

What I am doing is:

```
  /*
   * Determine if a given text contains invalid words
   * @param {string} text
   **/
  isInvalid(text) {
    return (
      this.blacklist.filter((word) => new RegExp(word, "i").test(text)).length >
      0
    );
  }
```

So, if I test the method with:

```
  myFilter.isInvalid("I love bananas")
```

it returns true.

But, if I try with:

```
  myFilter.isInvalid("I love banaaaaaanaaas"); // <- Multiple vowels
```

it returns false... and I need a true.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `blacklist`? Unsure how you expect it to be true.

Comment: blacklist = ["sandwhich", "banana", "cheese"...]

Comment: So you would have to write a reg exp that says "one or more times" for each letter since it is not a simple text search

Comment: @Raul ... `this.blacklist.filter( ... ).length > 0` is better rewritten into `this.blacklist.some( ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward approach might be creating a regex (from each blacklisted word) which recognizes any vowel within such a word and rewrites each vowel in a way that [within a regex pattern this very vowel will be searched as either ***once*** or ***many***](https://regex101.com/r/2PsUfp/1) and also can be consumed by an [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) function ...

```js
console.log(
  'bananas'.replace((/[aeiou]/ig), (match => `${ match }+`))
);
console.log(
  RegExp('bananas'.replace((/[aeiou]/ig), (match => `${ match }+`)), 'i')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... a method which implements the above then might be named `createVowelSequenceRegex` and used accordingly by the already existing validation method (`isInvalid`) ...

```js
function createVowelSequenceRegex(text) {
  return RegExp(text.replace((/[aeiou]/ig), (match => `${ match }+`)), 'i');
}
const sampleText = 'I love banaaaaaanaaas';

console.log(
  createVowelSequenceRegex("bananas"),
  createVowelSequenceRegex("bananas").test(sampleText)
);


function isInvalid(text) {
  return (
    blacklist.some(word =>
      createVowelSequenceRegex(word).test(text)
    )
  );
}
const blacklist = ["sandwhich", "banana", "cheese"];

console.log(
  'isInvalid("I love bananas") ?',
  isInvalid("I love bananas")
);
console.log(
  'isInvalid("I love banaaaaaanaaas") ?',
  isInvalid("I love banaaaaaanaaas")
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a regex that is this `/b+a+n+a+n+a+s+/`, you can probably achieve this by creating this pattern.

```js
const word = 'bananas'
// add a `+` after each character in the string
const pattern = word.split('').map(char => char + '+').join('') // "b+a+n+a+n+a+s+"
```

The `+` means the character before is repeated with occurrence >= 1

```js
new RegExp(pattern, 'i').test('banaaaaaanaaas') // true
```

---

However, if you only want vowels to repeat, you'll just need to check if the character is one of the vowels.

```js
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
const word = 'bananas'
// add a `+` after each vowel in the string
const pattern = word
  .split('')
  .map(char => vowels.indexOf(char) > -1 ? char + '+' : char)
  .join('') // "ba+na+na+s"
```

Comment: ... wasn't it much simpler, in order to create a regex pattern string, to make use of a `RegExp` (like `/[aeiou]/ig`) itself in combination with a string `replace`ment.

Comment: @Raul The first one doesn't just repeat vowels, it repeats every character. What are you trying to test?